# Office365 API does NOT say if Calendar is selected/enabled/visible on user's view?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Looking at documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#GetCalendars

The call GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars
Doesn't return any information whether the user has additional calendars selected/enabled/visible or not.

How do I know that from the API? Because the user might have a calendar added, but it's not selected, hence, user not using it actively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tell which calendars are visible or hidden. This is entirely controlled by the client and a user could very easily have different calendars selected on different devices and/or clients (i.e. I have different calendars showing up in Outlook 2016 for Windows than I have in my Windows 10 Calendar app or in Outlook for Android).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I guess Google Calendar API behaves differently because that one is synced across devices and the API does say which ones are selected and which ones are not